# PHP SimpleXMLElement XPath Selection

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following XML: http://pastebin.com/QiRK72BK

which is generated in response to a REST query. My code is very simple:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

var_dump($xml->getName());

var_dump($xml->xpath("serverDetail/apiEnv"));
```

in an attempted test case. The first var_dump reveals that the XML file is indeed being loaded:

```
 string(21) "GeneralSearchResponse"
```

However, the second var_dump puzzles me. I feel it should definitely match some data, but instead I get

```
array(0) { }
```

I've also tried the xpath "/serverDetail/apiEnv" "//apiEnv" and "/" and always get an empty array. Am I misunderstanding xpath or perhaps missing some initialization step?

Comment: Do you have a link to the original xml? Copy & Pasting your pastebin response freaks the hell out of simplexml_load_file for me.

Comment: The original link uses a private API key, but these demo credentials should work: http://sandbox.api.shopping.com/publisher/3.0/rest/GeneralSearch?apiKey=78b0db8a-0ee1-4939-a2f9-d3cd95ec0fcc&trackingId=7000610&keyword=013803105384

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML is using a namespace:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('u', 'urn:types.partner.api.shopping.com');
var_dump($xml->xpath("//u:serverDetail/u:apiEnv"));
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "sandbox"
  }
}
```

Edit: Dirty workaround, might be helpful though:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$xmlStr = str_replace("xmlns", "ns", $xml->asXML());
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);
var_dump($xml->xpath("serverDetail/apiEnv"));
```

Comment: Wow that, that's a bit abnoxious to have to prefix each element with a namespace alias but thannnk you!

Comment: Not only that, `registerXPathNamespace()` only works for the **next** xpath call. I've not done much with xml in ages, don't know if there's a better way.

Comment: Edited my response, maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll just stick with the cleaner way if only for performance and hope they don't change namespaces suddenly :)

Comment: Even if they do, just use a variable instead of `'urn:types.partner.api.shopping.com'` in every `registerXPathNamespace()`, that's exactly what it's for, aliasing namespaces.